# The name of $p\Longrightarrow q \equiv \neg p \lor q$ logical equivalence

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus

As we now the negation of the conditional statement $p\Longrightarrow q$ is $p\land\neg q$. Using De Morgan Law then we get:
$$p\Longrightarrow q \equiv \neg p \lor q.$$
Do you know if there is any name for this logical equivalence?

Comment: the implication rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Philosophers call the equivalence $p \rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee q$ the [material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) *rule*.

One should not confuse this with the [material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) *operation*, which we also sometimes call the *material implication operation*: this is just the name of the usual $\rightarrow$ connective itself.

In the usual (so-called classical) logic that we use in everyday mathematics, the material implication operation $\rightarrow$ obeys the material implication rule. But in certain alternative logical systems, for example in the intuitionistic logic literature, $\rightarrow$ is still often called material implication, even though it *does not* obey the material implication rule!

Comment: For OP's benefit: in this answer, while the symbols $\to$ and $\leftrightarrow$ are logical symbols, the symbols $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ are _metalogical_ symbols. That is, $p\to q$ is a logical formula, but $p\Rightarrow q$ describes a relation between the two logical formulas $p$ and $q$.

Comment: I'm not sure if this convention is universal. Judging by the original post, it may be that OP uses $\Leftrightarrow$ as a logical symbol and $\equiv$ as the corresponding metalogical symbol. (In this case I'm not sure how the metalogical equivalent of $\Rightarrow$ would be written.)

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying the correspondence between OP's notation and mine, @AkivaWeinberger. I elected to go with this notation because it's the one currently used by the Wikipedia article.